# Find a object in MongoDb via Array Value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

so im using mongodb,

```js
{
_id: 0123,
array: ['value 1','value 2']
},
{
_id: 01234,
array: ['value 3','value 4']
}
```

So I want to find a object that has `value 4` in it's array with mongodb's `findOne()`, how do I do that?

Do note that I don't know what `_id` the value is in, I want to find the value inside the array

Comment: db.collection.findOne( { array: { $in: [4] } }); For more information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#op._S_in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
db.collection.findOne( { array: { $in: ["value 4"] } })
```